# Tkinter save text in editor

Tags: python, tkinter

I went here: http://effbot.org/zone/vroom.htm
And tried this out:

```
filename = raw_input("Filename?")
editor = Text()
editor.pack(fill=Y, expand=1)
editor.config(font="Courier 12")
editor.focus_set()
mainloop()
#save
f = open(filename, "w")
text = str(editor.get(0.0,END))
try:
    f.write(text.rstrip())
    f.write("\n")
```

However, I was given an error:

```
TclError: invalid command name ".40632072L"
```

How can i fix this problem? 
I'm not comfortable with object-oriented programming, so I would prefer an imperative solution (without any `class` keywords).

Comment: Which line is producing that error?  Please print the entire stack trace.

Comment: Also, in the future, please post code that's complete enough to run. This is going to raise an obvious `SyntaxError` for having a `try` without an `except` or `finally`. (Also, as a side note, you really ought to convert the `open/try/finally/close` into a `with open`; that example you're looking at is ancient…)

Comment: Sorry, the complete code is really redundant. I will remember that next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that, after the mainloop finishes, all of your widgets, including `editor`, get destroyed, so you can't call `editor.get`.

What you want to do is add some code that stashes the value of `editor` in a plain old string while the main loop is running, and then use that variable. For example:

```
text=''
def stash(*args):
    global text
    text = str(editor.get(0.0,END))
editor.bind_all('<<Modified>>', stash)
```

---

Or, of course, do the simpler thing: write the file from within the GUI instead of after the GUI has exited. If you go look farther down the same page, you'll see how they do that.